# Incorrect layout after rotation if banner ads enabled outside of viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, layout, ios8, iad

I am having trouble with an iOS 8 app. My app needs to get information from a web server to determine if ads should be played or not. This can take a while, so the code in `viewDidLoad` doesn't wait for it and instead calls `setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO`. Then later, once the information comes in, `setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES` is called outside of `viewDidLoad`.

I have determined that I need to call `setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO` inside `viewDidLoad` otherwise `setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES` doesn't properly invoke the ads and generates lots of internal exceptions.

The issue is that once ads are enabled outside of `viewdidLoad`, the layout messes up. I've illustrated with two images below. The top one is "before", the bottom "after", as in after *Show Ads* is tapped.

Note in the "before" image that *Show Ads* and *Just a Label* both appear in their respective corners after rotation. In the "after" image, the landscape orientation is no longer correct. It maintains the portrait bounds with *Just a Label* and the banner ad cut off.

I have submitted a bug report to Apple and provided a sample project accessible on DropBox as [ID19658866.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2agt78787gmiaco/ID19658866.zip?dl=0). Feel free to download it and try it out.

If anyone can provide some insight, and maybe a solution where I don't have to change the logical sequence, i.e. not showing ads until after `viewDidLoad` is completed, that would be much appreciated.

[image: before *Show Ads* is tapped]  [image: after *Show Ads* is tapped]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these two lines in `viewdidLoad:`

```
[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];
[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO];
```

The first call sets up the ads correctly, the second right away makes sure they don't show. Later you can call `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];` and it will handle orientation changes without problem.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, [Yimin Rong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280717/1403046) will probably work, at least with the current SDK. But it feels a little strange. It doesn't really explain *why* it would work.

Looking at the documentation for `setCanDisplayBannerAds:` we see:

> It's important to note that this will modify the view hierarchy of the view controller by inserting a new container view above the view controller's view. The impact is that the view controller's view property will no longer return the originally provided view, it will return the new container. To access the original view, use the originalContentView property.

So it actually replaces your UIViewController's `.view` property. Keep that in mind.

When a UIViewController is displayed onscreen, it is resized to fit the whole screen (or at least the container it is taking up). Because of this, the UIViewController's `.view` property gets an [autoresizing mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, so its height and width are flexible, and it can stretch to fit the container.

When you call `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];` in `viewDidLoad`, your UIViewController's `.view` property gets replaced with a new UIView, and since it is in `viewDidLoad`, its `autoresizingMask` gets set appropriately. Conversely, calling `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO];` in `viewDidLoad` effectively does nothing.

In your sample app, when you call `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];` *outside* of `viewDidLoad`, we can see that the `autoresizingMask` does *not* in fact get set to stretch. This is what is causing the problem:

```
- (IBAction)TouchUpInside:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touch Up Inside");
    NSLog(@"Original View: %@", self.view);
    [self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];
    NSLog(@"New View: %@", self.view);
    NSLog(@"Content View: %@", self.originalContentView);
}

Output: 
2015-02-05 11:32:19.654 ID19658866[12404:3600041] Touch Up Inside
2015-02-05 11:32:19.655 ID19658866[12404:3600041] Original View: <UIView: 0x7f9c42717440; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c42717710>>
2015-02-05 11:32:19.666 ID19658866[12404:3600041] New View: <UIView: 0x7f9c42523fb0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c42524080>>
2015-02-05 11:32:19.666 ID19658866[12404:3600041] Content View: <UIView: 0x7f9c42717440; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c42717710>>
```

The key point here being in the 3rd line of output, where "New View" does *not* have `autoresize = W+H;` included in the output. We have also confirmed that `self.view` gets replaced by a new view in between the 2nd and 3rd lines of output.

To remedy this, we can make sure our new `self.view` property gets the required `autoresizingMask` by adding this line after we call `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];`:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

And it will work, and we will know why.

Or we could, you know... just replace our `self.view` property by calling `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];` within `viewDidLoad`, so it automatically gets the `autoresizingMask` set correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I think there's a typo about halfway down, the paragraph starting with "In your sample app, when you call...", I think it should be `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];` instead of `NO`?

Comment: Ah, you are right; fixed. Point is that calling it with `YES` changes the view hierarchy, and so calling it outside of `viewDidLoad` does not get the `autoresizingMask` set like it should be.

Comment: One thing I noticed, if I don't make any calls to `setCanDisplayBannerAds:` in `viewDidLoad`, and later enable the ads, the ads won't show and a lot of delegate-related exceptions are generated, so there might be more involved than just autoresizing.

Comment: Yes. There is a private API class called `_ADUIViewControllerAdController ` that is instantiated and connected to your view controller the first time you call `setCanDisplayBannerAds:` (regardless of whether or not you pass in `YES` or `NO`). This still has to be called before display (ie in `viewDidLoad`).  Then later on, you can call it again with `YES`, and things will work fine. The problem with stretching, however, is the `autoresizingMask`.

Comment: Keep your sample project the way it is, but add the autoresizing line of code into `TouchUpInside:`, without removing the `setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES` from `viewDidLoad` and it should work.

Comment: Do you mean without removing the `setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO` from `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1):

Total shot in the dark, but what happens if you call setNeedsLayout or setneedsupdatecontraint (provided you're using auto layout, which I would assume you are) once the ads come in?  Also, make sure your constraints are properly setup between the ad view and the others.  These probably are not the correct answer but I'm hoping it will provide some additional insight as to the real problem/solution.

Comment: Thanks, tried both of `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `setNeedsLayout`, and `setNeedsDisplay` individually and in combination - layout bug still there. Because it involves iAds, hoping to get a response from Apple sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yeah, I was confident these wouldn't be the solution but was hopeful you'd  see something that might shed some additional light on the real problem/solution.  Whatever you discover I hope you'll come back and update your posting with what you ultimately learn.  Thanks Buddy.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. Save Answers for answers and not guesses to grab the points.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, Yimin Rong has the best [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280717/4544199) out of all the available. However, if this is a premium v. standard account type of thing, wouldn't it be best if you were to keep a variable locally stored and have the user hit the "restore purchase" button. This way, even if the user were offline, you could display ads (if they were stored locally) and when they came online, you could collect your profits from the advertisers. Best of luck with your application!

Comment: Thank you. Agreed it would be better to have a local variable, but didn't want to modify the existing logic too much. This is the first release using the built-in banner ads. Also agreed Yimin Rong's solution is the cleanest, but I like the research effort provided by cjwirth.